# Subarray with given sum

Tags: c++

Given an unsorted array `A` of size `N` of non-negative integers, find a continuous sub-array which adds to a given number `S`.

Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines. The first line of each test case is N and S, where N is the size of array and S is the sum. The second line of each test case contains N space separated integers denoting the array elements.

Output:
For each testcase, in a new line, print the starting and ending positions(1 indexing) of first such occuring subarray from the left if sum equals to subarray, else print -1.

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= 107
1 <= Ai <= 1010
```

Example:
Input:

```
2
5 12
1 2 3 7 5
10 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Output:

```
2 4
1 5
```

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, n, s, a[1000], result[1000];
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        result[i * 2] = -1;
        cin >> n >> s;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> a[j];
        }
        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (flag == 0) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int k = j; k < n && sum < s; k++) {
                    sum += a[k];
                    if (sum == s) {
                        result[i * 2] = j + 1;
                        result[(i * 2) + 1] = k + 1;
                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < t * 2; i += 2) {
        if (result[i] != -1) {
            cout << result[i] << " " << result[i + 1] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << result[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:

```
4 225
9 45 10 190
```

Its Correct output is:

```
-1
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
-1-1-1-138 42
```

Comment: If you have the input that caused the wrong output, it's easy to do something that these competition sites doesn't teach you: ***Debugging!*** Different debugging techniques and being able to use a debugger is crucial for any programmer, even for hobbyists.

Comment: And on the matter of competition sites and teaching... They should *not* be considered teaching or learning resources! All they really teach are bad habits. And bad habits (as well as good) tend to stick. So please read [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), take a few classes, and learn C++ properly and with good habits before using competition sites as *training* resources.

Comment: Step one: slice this code into smaller functions, to separate: main, reading data, calculating result and printing. Step two: think if you can find answer by iterating over table only twice.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0ocgTgW464
However I believe that the time complexity is O(n*log(n)) given the fact that map::find is O(log(n))